# SSRS Solution Deployment

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have developed SSIS Package to fetch data from SharePoint Lists and importing to the SQL Server Tables. I am going to deploy this package as a Project Deployment Model.

From these SQL Tables, I have built SSRS Reporting Solution including few reports and Deployed it on my Development SharePoint Site.

But now, I have no idea how to send this solution with reports to the Client Side.

I have checked below utilities but not getting the exact idea of what I should do.

http://rsbuild.codeplex.com/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162839%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

SQL Server version I am using is SQL Server 2012 and Data tools version is also 2012.

Please guide me here.

Thank you,
Mittal.

Answer (score 0):

To deploy your reporting objects, you right-click on the project in Visual Studio then select deploy and configure the server to deploy to.

If you are trying to get an already deployed package, you can use the import wizard:
e.g.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270294.aspx

Then the report server can be accessed by the client browser - e.g. in internet explorer, browse to to: http:

> //reportserver/reports

Where "reportserver" can either be the server's ip address or reporting server name.

You can also modify these reports using the report builder tool, that will allow you to edit the rdl files on the server - e.g. when you browse to the reports, you can select edit with report builder.

If you are using sharepoint, you can use sharepoint authentication mode or you can set up access based on active directory groups at the folder level, if the client is browsing to the reports using the web browser.